# jQuery validate function Does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function(){

        jQuery("#agree").validate({
            expression: "if (!isChecked(SelfID)) return false; else return true;",
            message: "Please agree the terms and conditions"
        });   
   });

</script>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="agree" name="agree" id="agree"  />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this case? (We generally ask that questions come with a detailed explanation, over and above a short description in the title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the validation to the form element and set the required rule to the checkbox

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" value="agree" name="agree" id="agree" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            agree: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            agree: "Please agree the terms and conditions"
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2ejacepj/)